# Rotate elements by an increasing amount

Tags: css, sass, css-animations

I have an arbitrary number of `<div>` elements. I want each `<div>` to be rotated, but increasing by 2 degrees.  How should this be done?  I'm not sure if it is possible in just CSS,

For example:

```
div:nth-child(1) {
  rotate(0deg);
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(2deg);
}
div:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(4deg);
}

...
// Here is the general equation, but I can't use it in CSS.
div:nth-child(n) {
  transform: rotate( 2*n );
}
```

Comment: considered using sass?

Comment: yes - currently using sass, what are you thinking of? (I'm good with mixins and variables - but still not sure where the limits are of their other stuff

Comment: @cimmanon - tried hardcoding the CSS above. There wasn't much else to try in CSS given my knowledge (before this post).  Honestly I didn't realize SASS could do for loops or control structures.

Comment: did my answer work out?  please give feedback

Comment: @DonnyP And?  You have enough rep that you should know the rules by now.  You added the Sass tag, it is your job to research *first* to see what it can do.  The documentation is a single page, there's really no excuse for lazy questions like this.

Comment: @Cimmanon - there's no excuse for your rudeness either.

Comment: @maloman - will be implementing it later tonight and will accept or comment then, but looks good - thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$qty: 40;//number of childs
$step:  $qty *2 ;

@for $i from 0 through $qty - 1 {
div:nth-child(#{$i + 1}) {
    transform: rotate( $step+deg) ;
  }
}
```

[also check this](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while)

Answer (score 0):

Since child elements can be positioned relatively to their parent, you can increase them using:

```
 .parent div{
    transform:rotate(2deg);
 }
```

**DEMO**

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.parent div {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(2deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(2deg);
  transform: rotate(2deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <div>
                    <div>
                      <div></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @cimmanon: going by op they already have an *arbitrary number of <div> elements*. Also, to get [some effects, you might have to](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/raqRvK)

Comment: Yes, an arbitrary number of *sibling* elements, not *nested* elements.

Comment: @cimmanon: OP hasn't explicitly stated that, and code was purely a sample. Also, positioning these absolutely (top: 100%) would make this perfectly valid. What's exactly wrong with this solution? This gives a soultion perfectly valid, so I'm at a slight loss as to what's *the most awful thing I have ever seen.*

Comment: For a CSS/Sass question, it should be a given that you don't just go suggesting markup modifications unless there is absolutely no other way to solve the problem.  You're adding an excessive amount of extra markup for purely stylistic purposes, which is pretty terrible.  How do you not feel bad suggesting adding 179 extra elements to rotate an element by -2deg (or 358deg, however you prefer to look at it)?

Comment: @cimmanon: OP hasn't asked for 'adding 179 extra elements' - i think you're blowing this **completely out of proportion**. They have not stated how many elements they're looking to use. They're looking to add a rotation compared to the previous div. ***this does exactly that***. I've used this as a **demo**. So, unless you have some other approach, that means they can do exactly what they're looking to do, I believe this approach if fine for this functionality. OP has not asked to **rotate an element by -2deg**, so please explain to me what exactly doesn't work with this approach.

Comment: The *other* answer does "exactly that", too.  The difference here is that they haven't suggested modifying the markup.  Given that they are rotating the elements by 2deg, one can safely assume that the maximum number of variations would be 180 (360 / 2).  For all I know, they could have a total of 360 elements.  To suggest using markup to do this is, in my book, negligent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @jbutler483 - the help is appreciated. Cimmanon is right that this is inefficient, he just writes it in a pretty rude way. Regardless yours is still a solution.

Comment: Here I am using elements as I imagine them to be; note: **i am not adding elements**.